# Access Codebuild project from another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Currently we have a CodePipeline in account A. Some codebuild steps are deployed in account B to provision cloudformation stacks there and everytime we want to look for pipeline logs we need to switch account in order to access codebuild project details. Is there a way to access execution details in pipeline account?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Like for most other cases, the solution comes from using **cross-account roles**.

General info is here:

- [Tutorial: Delegate Access Across AWS Accounts Using IAM Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)

Basically what you need to do is as follows:

- Acc B creates an **assumable role** which grants access to the build steps in its account. The role must use Acc A as in its trust policy.
- Acc A has an IAM role or user which has permission to **assume the role** from Acc B.
- Once the role is assumed by an entity in Acc A, you can **access  resources** from Acc B.

If you attempt this and get into issues, please ask or make new question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for a way to check the Build project and run details, the best way would be to [share the project](https://%5B%5D%20Working%20with%20shared%20projects%20-%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/project-sharing.html) from Account B to Account A using AWS Resource Access Manager (AWS RAM).

NOTE: This will allow the consumer (users in Account A) only to view the Build project and builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to only access the logs from the other account CodeBuild project, you could create a cross account subscription as explained in these docs:

https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/CrossAccountSubscriptions.md